# While editing a question, this piece of text causes the error: "contain code that is not properly formatted"

Tags: bug, code, error-message

I am editing one of my questions on Stack Overflow.
It raises an error:

> Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as
> code.

[image]

After some digging, I find it is about [this text](https://pastebin.com/iJqxmgZm):
(Do not omit the 2 white spaces at end of line.)

A1, frame = 3187, time = 10.00139
A2, frame = 6495, time = 20.0001
A1, frame = 6496, time = 20.00392
A1, frame = 4534, time = 30.00224

This problem only occurs when editing questions.
If I'm asking a new question, it will not raise error.

I tested [this text](https://pastebin.com/iJqxmgZm) by trying to edit three questions. 
If I paste this text on the end of the question, it will raise the error. 
If I delete all the text and then paste this text, it will also raise the error.

I think it is a bug. 
I don't know any Markdown syntax treating the text as code.

Comment: You would not have the message if have formatted that text as quote. Because it is

Comment: I don't think it is a bug but I give you the error message and guidance we have on that quality feature is sparse if not lacking . Use code markup and or code fences if you have output to share that contains  punctuation characters.

Comment: @rene OK, I will use code fences next time.

Comment: @rene The error message is misleading, it confused me for an hour. According to the message, I thought there is something wrong in code text. I checked it again and again and found nothing. Finally I tried deleting each part of text one by one, and found the part that causes the error.

Comment: Yeah, that is unfortunately the technique I also use to diagnose these errors. Far from optimal for both the OP and those users on meta that try to support these problems.